# How can I directly access a PC in another subnet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, subnet

Ok so I have 2 subnets setup in my home network. There is a wireless router (with built in switch) connecting PC A (192.168.1.3) via a wire and PC B (192.168.1.101) via wifi.

There is a wired switch in another room. PC C connects to it and has IP address 10.42.0.64. PC B also connects to the wired switch and has IP address 10.42.0.1
on that subnet.

I've used the network configuration GUI on PC B and set eth0 (10.42.0.1) as "shared to other computers". With this setup I can access the internet and PC A from the other room.

I've also added a static route on the wireless router, using 192.168.1.101 as the gateway and 10.42.0.0 as the destination network. After adding the route, I can access PC B from PC A using any of it's IP addresses, but I can't access PC C, which is what I need.

I've got samba and some web services running on PC C and I need access to them from PC A, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's my setup visualized:

[image: http://files.mitikaz.com/netsetup.png]

Comment: -1  not only do you not show your gateway 192.168.1.101 in your picture, but you also talk in comment about eth0 and wlan0 being part of the solution, which you do not show in your picture either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure PC B to act as a router between the two subnets, e.g., see [Setting up an Ubuntu Wired/Wireless Router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router) as explained at the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/) site. Alternatively, for accessing just the web services running on C from A, you could install proxy server software, such as [Squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software)) or one of many other proxy server applications, on B and then configure browsers on A to use B as a proxy server.  Or, if B is functioning as a [Secure Shell (SSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) server, most SSH clients allow you to establish a dynamic [SOCKS proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) on the SSH server when you establish an SSH connection to it. You can [tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) all sorts of TCP traffic through a SOCKS proxy not just HTTP/HTTPS traffic You should be able to tunnel [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) traffic, though I've never done that myself. E.g., see the accepted answer to [SMB proxy: Connect to SMB server through SSH tunnel between two other hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/356369/smb-proxy-connect-to-smb-server-through-ssh-tunnel-between-two-other-hosts) at Server Fault.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The router setup guide helped setup a bridge between eth0 and wlan0. That's all I needed. Everything works now.

Comment: @GeorgeSechu  You write "The router setup guide helped setup a bridge between eth0 and wlan0. That's all I needed. "  <-- this answer said nothing about setting up a bridge, so why accept it.

Comment: Moonpoint, is that guide more about setting up wireless clients than wireless routers?

Comment: @GeorgeSechu  furthermore, your question said nothing about eth0 and wlan0 . And more than that.. Would bridging even work when they are on different subnets?

Comment: @barlop You're right the answer didn't but the setting up a bridge was part of the guide so I'm glad I was pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @barlop eth0 and wlan0 are the interfaces on PC B. Bridging them and using the bridge IP as a gateway works for me.

Comment: @barlop, the guide is about configuring a computer running the Ubuntu Linux operating system to function as a router and includes instructions on setting up a [network bridge](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router) on an Ubuntu system. Though George Sechu's question didn't reference the name assigned to the wireless interface in system B, the Ubuntu system, only the wired interface, eth0, his diagram shows the Ubuntu system has a wired and a wireless interface; on Ubuntu systems eth0 and wlan0 are commonly  respective designations for those interfaces.